# Regular Expression, optional character on multiple locations but result must contain at least once

Tags: regex

I am performing a string search where I am looking for the following three strings:

```
XXX-99-X
XXX-99X
XXX99-X
```

So far I have:

```
([A-Z]{3}(-?)[0-9]{2}(-?)[A-Z]{1})
```

How do I enforce that `-` has to be present at least once in either of the two possible locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an alternation, to match either a `-` and optional `-` at the left or `-` at the right part.

Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern.

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?:-[0-9]{2}-?|[0-9]{2}-)[A-Z]$
```

- `^[A-Z]{3}`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[0-9]{2}-?|[0-9]{2}-` Match either  `-` 2 digits and optional `-` Or  2 digits and `-`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` end of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4rKfo/1)

Or use a positive lookahead to assert a `-` at the right

```
^(?=[^-\r\n]*-)[A-Z]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[A-Z]$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^-\r\n]*-)` Positive lookahead, assert a `-` at the right
- `[A-Z]{3}-?` Match 3 chars A-Z and optional `-`
- `[0-9]{2}-?` Match 2 digits and optional `-`
- `[A-Z]` Match a single char A-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CvV1NV/1)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?:-?\d{2}-|-\d{2})[A-Z]+$
```

[online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/9pPzIp/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^[A-Z]{3}        ##Matching if value starts with 3 alphabets here.
(?:              ##Starting a non capturing group here.
   -?\d{2}-      ##Matching -(optional) followed by 2 digits followed by -
   |
   -\d{2}        ##Matching dash followed by 2 digits.
)                ##Closing very first capturing group.
[A-Z]+$          ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of capital letters at the end of value.
```